# Вывести все записи из одной таблицы за исключением тех, которые есть в другой

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица `Log` c первичный ключом `LogId`.
Так же есть таблица `UserLog` с полем `userlogIdLog`.

Связь таблиц такая:

```
Log.LogId = UserLog.userlogIdLog
```

Необходимо вывести все записи из таблицы `Log` за исключением тех, которые есть в `UserLog`. При этом записей в `userlog` может и не быть.

Вот что сделал:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  log
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
  userlog ul
ON
  ul.userlogIdLog = log.LogId
WHERE
  log.LogId IS NULL
```

Comment: мб `LEFT JOIN ... WHERE ul.userlogIdLog IS NULL`

Comment: хм..вот пример наглядный для RIGHT OUTHER JOIN
http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html

Comment: вот наглядный пример, чего вам не хватает ?http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/597e9/6

Comment: вот тут с RIGHT JOIN если очень хочется :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/597e9/10

Comment: Наверное вот это: 'несуществующая связь'

Comment: Ну вот, и зачем там right join ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Так как вам необходимо извлечь записи из таблицы `log` разумнее воспользоваться пересечением `LEFT JOIN`, который гарантирует, что будут извлечены все записи из `log`, которые вы сможете отфильтроваться в WHERE-условии

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  log
LEFT JOIN
  userlog ul
ON
  ul.userlogIdLog = log.LogId
WHERE
  ul.userlogIdLog IS NULL
```

Comment: вместо WHERE можно AND